# Why is VirtualBox using more memory than configured?

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I'm running 2 virtual machines with VirtualBox: ubuntu (7586MB of memory) and Win10 (3506MB of memory). The host machine is Ubuntu 18.04 with 16GB of RAM and 14GB of swap. Although 7.5+3.5 is barely 11GB of memory, the host machine is using just around 16GB of memory. I observed, that VirtualBox VMs are using RSS and SHR, hence it's probably using more memory than it's supposed to.

top's output:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                               
 1625 loj       20   0 6957588 3,597g 3,589g S  52,9 23,4  69:59.89 VirtualBox                                                                                                            
 1679 loj       20   0 9385696 7,459g 7,451g S   5,9 48,5  22:34.60 VBoxHeadless
```

Is there a way to "optimize" memory usage, so that a VM would consume less memory?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Question [66842](https://superuser.com/questions/66842/how-does-virtualboxs-memory-usage-work) is asking why is VirtualBox using more memory, than it's reported in task manager. I'm asking why is VirtualBox consuming more memory, than it's configured for VMs (and how to overcome that).

Comment: Could somebody explain, why downvotes?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few examples of programs that run no VMs and consume memory anyway:

- Firefox
- Chrome
- Word
- Paint
- Notepad

VirtualBox is consuming more memory than allocated for VMs for the same reason: computer programs need memory to run. It's also the reason why you have to assign any memory to a VM.

Comment: I'm using VirtualBox for a long time. I noticed that it was very memory efficient about 5 years ago (it counsumed about that much memory, that was used inside VMs (with guest additions installed), but now, it consumes much more memory than sum of maximum configured of all VMs.

Comment: If you want to reduce memory footprint, you could try to disable paravirtualization. It will affect performance, though.